# Restarting Eureka does not seem to work for Prana

Tags: node.js, yaml, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am getting the following error when I restart Eureka:

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>   Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: prana

There is a latency in prana that seems to cause this problem.  After a while the prana sidecar seems to start working. Any clues? likely a configuration setting.  Spring cloud based apps work fine.  Its just the non-jvm based apps which depend upon Prana that don't.

Comment: both ribbon and eureka can take up to 30 seconds each to warm their caches. If you're using spring-cloud, have you tried spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar rather than prana?

Comment: Yep.  I am using spring's sidecar.  Is there a setting that can refresh the cache?  I thought this one should do it (perhaps not)  registry-fetch-interval-seconds.  I set this one for 5 s

Comment: I would only alter these configurations if you have a good reason for it since the code assumes 30 sec a few times. The documentation also contains something like this. http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html "In production it’s probably better to stick with the default because there are some computations internally in the server that make assumptions about the lease renewal period."